# Como proteger method post

Tags: php, post

Galera é o seguinte eu tenho um method post que o cara ganha dinheiro por ele, essa noite passada os cara hackearam todo o dinheiro do site com o programa postman, enviando os pontos para ele pelo method post do programa, existe alguma forma de proteger esses dados para que ninguem possa fazer isso? Ou bloquear a página para que só o servidor contenha acesso a ela?

Comment: Está usando api no seu sistema?

Comment: Não estou usando é php puro

Comment: Sem conhecer a regra de negócio que você implementou fica um pouco complicado dar alguma sugestão. Mas como quer que somente o servidor tenha acesso, poderia verificar de onde vem a requisição usando o $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] , com isso valida se veio do seu servidor onde está o sistema. Com isso, teoricamente, somente o seu servidor poderia enviar requisições para essa funcionalidade.

Comment: @Marlysson isso deu um erro pra mim...

Comment: Que erro? Pesquise o que significa essa var global do php, o porque ela lhe é útil, e atualize a questão com seu erro tentado.